# Why does my webpage look different when I connect using different routers?! Does routers cache files?

Tags: internet, router, cache

Here is the case, I am working on a site from office and home, I recently updated the stylesheets and logged in the live site from office (using my same laptop I use all the time), and everything looks okay, I come home use my home internet connection to connect to the site using the SAME laptop, the styles are not updated!

The thing is: this happens on ALL browsers, and after emptying the cache many times, and even after one month of work, and even if I have never opened the site before on that browser (as if my router has a cache of its own)

Another thing: only one particular styles.css file seem to be hanging

Extra info: I use the same IP for my home wireless router as that defined in the office, the usual 192.168.0.1

Comment: i was just waiting till we upoload a newer version, we did, the cache did not revive :( i think i need a creative solution for this one

Answer (score 2):

1. Who is hosting the website? your work or a 3rd party (squarespace, godaddy)
2. If it's hosted by your work, are you uploading your content to a production server? Some businesses have a test server where sites can be tested out before they go live on the internet.
3. If it's a 3rd party... it could be a caching issue with your ISP... ISP's usually update their cache very frequently but sometimes things get stuck.
4. Can you edit / upload changes to the page? Try doing so and see if things change at home.

Comment: we use godaddy to host, and I think the development team did upload few patches, its just the damn css that is not refreshing, anyway i have to double check if i can upload a new css and get it to refresh... but if it is an ISP cache, does that mean it'll go away in couple of weeks?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you've already checked to verify that your request is going to the same server regardless of where you are[1], the other major possibility is that the server may be configured to display different versions of the page for "internal" vs. "external" visitors, based on the IP address that the request comes from[2].

The most likely solution for either of these would be to set up a VPN to connect you into the office network so that the web server will see your requests as coming from an "internal" IP address.

[1]  Checking that the hostname resolves to the same IP address from both locations is a decent, but not foolproof, way of doing this.

[2]  This would be the router's internet-facing address, not the 192.168.x.y address.